# MySQL Load Data Local Infile not allowed

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am building a stock syncing system between an in-store Point of Sale system (Tower) and a custom website. I am having issues running the command "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE".

PHPMyAdmin reports

> "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

Below is a paste of my entire query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'/home/ccgifts/tower/STOCKIMAGES30112018171438.zip' 
INTO TABLE temp_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(
`web_store_price`, `stk_webtax_group`, `trade_price`, 
`tax_level`, `tax_group`, `supplier_name`, 
`supplier_code`, `subcat_name`, `subcat_code`, 
`stock_supplier_code`, `short_description`, `rrp`, 
`retail_price`, `qty`, `plu`, `gst_payable`, 
`gst_credit`, `extra_description`, `description`, 
`department_name`, `department`, `cost_price`, `cost_ex`, 
`category_name`, `category`, `barcode`, `author`
)
```

I am on a fairly typical cPanel/WHM CentOS Setup, not shared hosting. It's my own VPS instance so I have root access etc. I have had my hosting technicians try to add permissions for MySQL so that I can run this command.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Scott

Comment: Check your Linux and MySQL permissions, because your error message points in this direction.

Comment: You need to check if server configured to accept LOAD DATA LOCAL (check local_infile variable) and MySQL used have FILE privileges: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: In addition, you cannot load zip file, you have to unpack it first.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to edit my mysql config to enable LOCAL INFILE. I logged in via SSH and ran the command successfully, however running it via PHPMYADMIN still results in the same error. I tried logging in via root WHM, and also via the user via cPanel. Both PhpMyAdmin instances output the error. Next I will try within my php script to see what happens.

Comment: PS - That file was not meant to be a zip file, it's actually a .csv.